# How to make use of `gt` and `fields` in the same query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-query

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986099/searching-nested-documents-for-a-field-regardless-of-the-positioning-of-the-fiel), I was introduced to the `fields` in a `query_string` query and how it can help me to search nested fields of a document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["*.id","id"],
      "query": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

But it only works for matching, what if I want to do some comparison? After some reading and testing, it seems queries like `range` do not support `fields`. Is there any way I can perform a `range` query, e.g. on a date, over a field that can be scattered anywhere in the document hierarchy?

i.e. considering the following document:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "Comment" : "Comment 1",
    "date" : "2016-08-16T15:22:36.967489",
    "Reply" : [ {
        "id" : 2,
        "Comment" : "Inner comment",
        "date" : "2016-08-16T16:22:36.967489"
    } ]
}
```

Is there a query searching over the `date` field (like `date > '2016-08-16T16:00:00.000000'`) which matches the given document, because of the nested field, without explicitly giving the address to `Reply.date`? Something like this (I know the following query is incorrect):

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "date" : {
                "gte" : "2016-08-16T16:00:00.000000",
            },
            "fields": ["date", "*.date"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `range` query itself doesn't support it, however, you can leverage the `query_string` query (again) and the fact that you can wildcard fields and that it supports range queries in order to achieve what you need:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\*date:[2016-08-16T16:00:00.000Z TO *]"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query will return your document because `Reply.date` matches `*date`

Comment: Could you please explain / refer to a documentation on what the `\*` is doing? And should I be using `fields` as before?

Comment: It's in the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names) document in the "Field names" section. You  don't need to use `fields` at all, the wildcard makes it unnecessary. `\*date` means any field ending with `date` (including nested ones). The backslash is there because we need to escape the wildcard `*` which is a reserved character in the query string syntax.